# Add new record in access form by incrementing one business day to a field and the rest blanck

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've an Access Form linked to 1 Table ( to make things easier ) .
I'd like to add a new record by Incrementing the DATE FIELD to the next Business Day .
Field n .value = Field n-1 . value + 1 Business day.
I know that manipulating Access Form are made either by the DoCmd or by Recordset :
I did not find Solution with DoCmd and i do not Master Recorset.

Can you please Help to only Increment one Field with one Bysiness day.
All other Fields stay Empty.

Regards.

Comment: You can have data entry enabled on the subform with default values in the table. Should be a pretty simple set up . You can also enabled whatever event you want to control the insertion fo the new data to hard code dateadd("D", 1, DATE()). There's tons of different ways ti skin this cat - so its up to you to figure out the best way too approach - my suggestion is to make it seamless with the end user process.

Comment: Hi : Thank you for the Answer. But, first of all there's no Direct VBA function for the "add 1 Business day" it is a Built in Function . I thought about the default value: but how to link it with the last Record . I would like to arrange a range , a series of records id,id+1 by date , date+1 Business day .Regards .

Answer (score 0):

You can build the following querys and execute it every time the database gets opened for example:

```
'Query1: Check if you already added the date for this day
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.YourDate = Date()

'Query2: Add dataset with Date + 1
INSERT INTO Table1 (YourDate) SELECT Date() + 1 As Expr
```

Now add the following code at load event of your database or form:

```
If DCount("*", "Query1") = 0 Then
  Exit Sub
Else
  Docmd.Execute "Query2", dbFailOnError
End If
```

Comment: We can not use the Function DATEADD(   , , ) since we need to add Business Days and not Calendar Days. Other point, the Insertion must firstly be made on the form , after comes the Table . The form contains Multiple Fields, the Date is only one field.       Thank You.